# Softkeyboard not displaying in 2.2 landscape mode

Tags: android

I am facing a strange problem. 
My app works fine in 2.1 (emulator + device). But, when I use 2.2 
(both emulator + device) then there is an issue with the soft 
keyboard. 
There is a Activity in landscape mode in the app (use 
android:screenOrientation="landscape"). 
There are two EditText in that Activity. But, soft keyboard is not 
displaying for those. In fact, softkeyboard seems to apprear, but as a 
bar in the bottom. 
Please view the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated. 
Regards 
Sarwar Erfan

tried different things for android:windowSoftInputMode , did not work

```
<Activity android:name=".PriceCalculator" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan" 
    android:configChanges="orientation" 
    android:label="Pricing Calculator">
    ....
</Activity>


<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/adhesiveUnitPrice" 
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi" 
    android:layout_column="4" android:gravity="right"/>
```

Comment: What is this option doing ? : flagNoExtractUi

Comment: That option does not help. I found out that, in 2.3, the softkeyboard wont show up in landscape mode if the emulator or the device has an hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that, in 2.3, the softkeyboard wont show up in landscape mode if the emulator or the device has an hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my code (see example here bellow). FYI, replacing "InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT" by "InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED" solved the issue.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);

    et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    final Context context = this;

    et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.requestFocusFromTouch();

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Did you test on a real device having Android 2.2 and physical keyboard? Which device did you test on?

Comment: Actually, I didn't. But I tested the code here above on an HTC WildFire (it runs on Android 2.2 but does not have any physical keyboard). In landscape mode, if you replace SHOW_FORCED by SHOW_IMPLICIT, the softbeyboard will not be triggered.

Comment: FYI. With the emulator (Android 2.2 + physical keyboard), in landscape mode, the softkeyboard is not triggered with the code here above.

Comment: Then it is not solved. The Keyboard comes out on 2.2 when there no physical keyboard (that is the case or your WildFire)
And, in the emulator, as it has physical keyboard, the keyboard does not come out. The situation is same as I mentioned.