# softkeyboard doesn't show in landscape mode in android 2.2 and above

Tags: android

i have made app which worked 2.2 and above version.
Softkeyboard is showing in portrait mode.
but Softkeyboard doesn't show in landscape mode.

i can only test it on emulator.

it is showing just like the below link.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242985/softkeyboard-not-displaying-in-2-2-landscape-mode)